# tuple<int, 3> t1(1), t2(2), t3(3);

Tags: c++, tuples

I know that tuple is an object that holds a collection of elements. I've encountered tuples like `tuple<int, double, string> student{15, 13.2, "Mike"}` but I've encountered one that I don't seem to understand, `tuple<int, 3> t1(1), t2(2), t3(3);` the first argument is an integer and then what does `3` represent, along with all the `t()`? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no such `std::tuple` in the standard library. `std::tuple` only accepts types as its template arguments (`template <class... Types> class tuple;`). Whatever you are reading this in either has its own non-standard `tuple` type, or it won't compile.

Comment: If `tuple` means `std::tuple` from the  standard library then that code shouldn't compile. `std::tuple` only takes types as its template arguments. Either that or it's someone else's tuple class.

Answer (score 2):

You should be getting something like this:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class ...> class std::tuple’
error: expected a type, got ‘3’
...
```

Clearly the compiler says that there is not such a constructor for `std::tuple`. You should check if the code you are using uses its own tuple, instead of the standard.

If this is `std::tuple`, then this code will not compile, it's wrong.

Check also the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/tuple/), where you can see that the compiler is (as usual) right.

---

PS - Next time format your question better because I took the wrong impression and made a pointless answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is not `std::tuple`; it is someone else's tuple type. Therefore, you will have to ask them.